# weaspyrint does not render uploaded image from database

Tags: javascript, django

**So here is my html code for the pdf**

```
<div class="cont">
     <img class="logo1" src="{% static 'upload/' %}{{ wmsu_logo.img_name }}" />

     <div>
       <p>Republic of the Philippines</p>
       <p>Western Mindanao State University</p>
       <p>{{ syllabus.college }}</p>
       <p class="title">DEPARTMENT OF {{ syllabus.department }}</p>
     </div>

     <img class="logo2" src="{% static 'upload/' %}{{ course_logo.img_name }}" />

     <img class="logo3" src="{% static 'upload/' %}{{ iso_logo.img_name }}" />
</div>
```

**and this is the view where it processes things.**

```
def pdf(request, id):
    # ---------- SYLLABUS ----------
    syllabus = get_object_or_404(Syllabus, user_id=request.user, id=id)

    # ---------- SYLLABUS TEMPLATE ----------
    syllabus_template = get_object_or_404(Syllabus_Template, user_id=request.user, id=syllabus.syllabus_template_id.id)
    wmsu_logo = Logo.objects.get(syllabus_template_id=syllabus_template, name='wmsu_logo')
    course_logo = Logo.objects.get(syllabus_template_id=syllabus_template, name='course_logo')
    iso_logo = Logo.objects.get(syllabus_template_id=syllabus_template, name='iso_logo')
    
    total_term_percentage = midterm.term_percentage + finalterm.term_percentage   

    template = loader.get_template('PDF_template/template.html') # Load HTML template
    html_string = template.render({

        'wmsu_logo': wmsu_logo,
        'course_logo': course_logo,
        'iso_logo': iso_logo,
}) # Render the template

    # Generate the PDF using WeasyPrint
    pdf = HTML(string=html_string, base_url=request.build_absolute_uri()).write_pdf()

    # Create an HttpResponse with the PDF content
    response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
    # Display in the browser
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=Syllabus' + str(datetime.datetime.now()) + '.pdf'

    return response
```

I need the uploaded image in the pdf conversion in weasyprint. I already deployed this in pythonanywhere. When I use the local file the image renders but when I deploy it, it does not render the image. I tried every possible way. Please recommend a fix to this I really need it. Please help.

Comment: What response do you get when it fails to render the image? Are there errors in your error log?

Comment: there is no error. When I convert the html to pdf in a local machine the image appears but when I deploy it, the image does not appear. @Glenn

Comment: That sounds like you are rendering an empty page, then. I see that you are using relative paths, so see https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/NoSuchFileOrDirectory/

Comment: Are you doing collectstatic after deploying?

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing "collectstatic" after deploying? Also, you need to correctly configure the static directory for the production environment